# How to make a cheatsheet/crib sheet using Pages

Tags: pages

I am starting a Developers Meet-up group at my sons' middle school, and I am trying to get ready for the first one.  I need to make a cheatsheet/crib sheet for the participants ala http://www.cheatography.com/ in Pages, but I am struggling with getting the boxes to work.

What I need to make is something like a bordered Text Box, with the first line being a title section that has a background color, followed by some text in the body of the Text Box that is simply white background.  Basically it should look like a little "window", with a colored title at the top and contents under it.

I can get the Text Box inserted, and I have a 1px border setup no problem, but I can't figure out how to get the title section to work.  In fact, I can't even find where to set the background color of the text.  I don't use Pages very often so I am struggling a lot to figure out where things are.

Once I get the Text Box working, I then need to be able to quickly replicate the Text Boxes for the various sections of the cheatsheet.  I am hoping I can simply copy/paste more of them into the document and resize them as needed.

**For the curious:**  The reason I am trying to do this in Pages is because my sons' school is an Apple Distinguished School.  All the computers at the school are Macs, and all the students have iPads.  Doing it in Pages allows them to park the digital copy somewhere the students can get to it to view/edit/print as necessary.  I don't want to use http://www.cheatography.com/ because some of the details I need to include in the cheatsheet would not be appropriate to share outside of the school.  My fallback will be to simply do this using HTML, but I'd rather this be in Pages.

Comment: Instead of using a **Text Box** I'd suggest using a **Table** as it offers more options to achieve the results you're looking for more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Numbers.app and it's tables.

You get better control over tables in Numbers. With simple things like resizing and not having to change setting to make the table stick in place like tables in Pages.

For this example I simply pasted the info from the site you provided straight into a blank sheet because they use tables. Which means the data will past as a Numbers table.

I then added a row for the title header.

I could easily make the table from scratch and also coping a whole table is as easy as selecting the table, copy, paste.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  I can actually add the tables directly in Pages, set the alignment to Around, and size things down as needed.  Thanks!